# Do all MacBook Pro 13.3" retinas have the same LCD panel dimensions?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

The MacBook Pro 13" Retina models from Late 2013 to Early 2015 are mostly compatible with each other with some firmware differences. The geometry of the displays in terms of thickness, corner radii and dimensions are identical.

[image: An A1502 bare panel fits late 2013 to early 2015 models][image: An A1402 bare panel fits 2012 through early 2013]

Is this also true for later models from late 2015 to the present? I am aware the electronics and cabling are different, but I am only concerned about them in regards to general fitment within the top cover housing.

[image: An A1706 A1708]

There's a good chance that all the displays have the same in terms of length and width since displays have a standard size. The A1502 panels were made by LG and Samsung and the two vendor parts are interchangeable. I highly doubt Apple or their vendors would incur the significant expense in tooling for panels with little to no difference in overall function.

What's not so clear is the thickness and in particular the radii of the corners. According to the following article, Apple doesn't adhere to a rounded rectangle, but uses a "squircle" for its corners as part of its design language:

https://hackernoon.com/apples-icons-have-that-shape-for-a-very-good-reason-720d4e7c8a14

Comment: It's also not clear if the two displays have the same type and placement of connectors, for the cable(s) that lead to the motherboard. This may matter to the OP.

Comment: I only care about the cables or any feature as it concerns fitment on the display cover.